# Prove that the sum of a series is 1

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Hello i am trying this exercise:

Use the MacLaurin series of the function $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$ to prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!} =1$$

To prove this i differentiated the series

$$f(x)=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}$$

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-1)}{(n-1)!}x^{2n-2}$$

but i don't see how to use that $f'(0)=1$ to prove that. I rewrote the expression as

$$1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{2^{n}n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n!} (\frac{1}{2})^{n} =1$$

but that is as far i go, can anyone help me to see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term-wise derivative of 
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}$$
is
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(2n+1)x^{2n}}{n!}.$$
I think you want to have a look at $f'(1/\sqrt 2)$.

Comment: Thank you i saw what i did wrong.